# Is SO the correct place to post a question about too many shortcuts slowing execution of code?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

So if I have a situation in which I have added so many shortcut conditions to my code that were originally intended to skip parts of the program when they were unnecessary and I think I might have inadvertently slowed my program down as a result, is it better to post my question to SO, or would it be a better fit for Code Review SE?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest profiling the code yourself to identify / fix the cause of the slowdown - the ability to profile code, analyse the results, and make appropriate changes, is a useful set of tools for a programmer to have in their toolbox.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the logic of your code is working, it would be better to post your question on Code Review. It sounds like you're looking for tips on refactoring your code for performance, which is one of the things CR was created for.